# Overriding __str__ allows string passed in foreign key field Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a form in Django that allows a lecturer to select units that have been created in the db.
When the dropdown menu is clicked, it shows something like Unit object (ICT270) 
that is why I override the Unit model **str** function to return self.code
and self.code is the primary key of the Unit model.
Apparently, after I do this, everytime I need to fill in the foreign key field to the Unit model, I can just pass in a string instead of the Unit object itself. Passing a Unit object works as well. for example, Class.objects.filter(unit_id='ICT270').first().
In the past, I need to pass a Unit object, not a string.
I am a bit worried about this, I feel vulnerable if I can pass a string like that.
Do you think this is an unexpected behavior or perfectly safe if the **str** includes all primary keys of that model?
thank you

edit : or instead overriding the **str** in the models.py, can I override it in forms.py? so that the str function will not work in other code. thanks

Comment: This isn't the case. Defining the str method doesn't at all change how you set or access values.

Comment: @DanielRoseman weirdly, Class.objects.filter(unit_id='ICT270').first().exists() returns True and unit_id is a foreign key field to the Unit model

Comment: So show your models.py with all the FK and PK definitions.

Comment: It sounds like "ICT270" is the primary key of the Unit model. As Ivan says, show your model definitions.